# Does an asp.net web-server run a new instance of a web application per request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application with private/protected methods or private/protected variables

First I would like to know when a web-server has a connection established already for a certain web application and then receives a new connection does it run a new instance of the web  application for this new connection and thus re-initializing all the variables in that web application just like on a computer?

I have goggled the Internet and I am terribly confused!

Second I am using the visual studio development server and I have learned that it doesn't accept connections from other computers, I have gotten around this by using a port forwarding software. So the question is, By doing this does VS2010 web-server see each different requests as a new request or same request since am forwarding them from an app on the local computer?

Finally if I have a web application open on one browser and then decide to open it on another browser and keep the current browser open is this treated as a new request or a post-back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The app domain is constant (can be recycled) and is created only on the first request (also can be set before that).

That is to say all the static variables are initialized only once
but all the not static classes on which your request depends are initialized on every request.

So basically all your pages in normal asp.net and all the controllers in asp.net MVC are initialized on every request.

read more about it here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle

[image]

*note - the image has been take from the article referred above

Comment: so lets say i have webform1.aspx page with a webform1.aspx.cs class which contains protected/private static variables in it. so do all those variables in that webform1.aspx.cs class get re-initialized for every new request for that page/class?

Comment: Constant is not correct; app-domains and app-pools are recycled periodically. "On the first request" is also not correct - it can be set to initialise *before* this.

Comment: @Fabio the page instance is indeed per request; any *instance* variables are reinitialized. However, static fields are per-app-domain so are shared between **all** requests by **all** users. Static fields are usually a **very  bad idea** in a web application

Comment: @ParvSharma Ok I understand what you mean by static variable but now I have a problem I renamed or change my protected static variables to just protected variables but when I add them to a session and try to retrieve them on another page I get Null/empty variable which shouldn't be the case as a user would have populated them on the previous page. Before I was using static and this was no issue now what do I do. Is there another way to transfer variables to another page without using sessions and not loosing data?

Comment: persist them in database.. or somewhere else.. thats the only way

Comment: @ParvSharma...  I figured out that I have to use Viewstate or Session to store data and it worked thx for your help :)

Comment: @ParvSharma I meant to say I had to use viewsate to populate the variables on each roundtrip thus preventing re-initializing and then use session to transfer them to a new page.

Comment: yeah that is the correct way.. also if you just wanna save users data for a redirect use can use TempData instead of session storage.

Answer (score 1):

Its a little more complicated than that. The process is optimised for mutiple connections and is stateless, however cashing can be used to imporve scalabilty: That which does not need to be reprocessed can simply be reused: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article821-beginners-guide-how-iis-process-aspnet-request.aspx is a good place to start understanding what can go on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx is a somewhat dryer ms version "iis asp page life cycle" is a good google

Comment: your first was somewhat helpful but the second one i had passed before and I simply can't grasp what it's talking about...anywhere the first link only explains what happens on the first request I want to know what is happening on the second,third or fourth request. So far the solution with the drawings is what i am looking for basically what I was doing wrong was declaring static variables in the asp.net pages but now when i add the variables to a session and try to retrieve them on a new page I get null variables/empty variables? why is that before when they were static this wasn't a problem.

Comment: Yes MS articles seem to be that way. When you understand the subject, they make sense, otherwise they are opaque. The following article doent have any diagrams, but is a IMHO good discussion of the various option to maintain state and how to use them. Because you have so many ways, none of them works by default, so you need to explcitly save and restore session state. http://aspdotnetdevs.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/aspnet-session-state-and-modes.html Personally I opt for the SQL option usually.

Comment: sorry I beat you to it....I just spend the last three hours figuring out that I have to use Viewstate to save variables data for roundtrips in the same page otherwise they will keep getting re-initializing and I have to use session to store data to pass onto the next page... Anyways thx for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

The web application instance handles many many requests. And shared state (cache etc) is used very effectively across those requests, whether for a single session or multiple concurrent sessions.

When a request is made, the *request* object (and any "page" / "controller" object) is created for that request. The state of this object is fresh, but systems like "session state", "view state", cookies, and request values can be used to repopulate it - sometimes largely automated.

A single user making separate requests is not a post-back. They are separate sessions, but even a single session that opens the same page twice (tabs, etc) is not a post-back. It mainly depends on the http verb and other evidences to determine a post-back.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to read this great article: https://lowleveldesign.org/2011/07/20/global-asax-in-asp-net/ for your question. Though it's a little late, it may help others out.