# Updating a variable during an asynchronous request in ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**CODE:**

I have a process that takes a long time to complete. Let's call it `LongProcess`. I want to poll every so often on the **Client Side** to get the `Status` of that process. My end goal is to use the value from `Status` to update a progress bar.

Here's the basic setup, from the Controller:

```
    // get the current status
    public JsonResult GetStatus()
    {
        return new JsonResult(Status);
    }

    public void SetStatus(int i)
    {
        Status = i;
    }

    // runs for 20 seconds, updates status while it runs
    public JsonResult LongProcess()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            SetStatus(i);
        }

        return new JsonResult("Done");
    }
```

In the View, I make a request to `LongProcess` using ajax. While that request processes, I call `updateStatus` every 250 milliseconds to update the progress bar with the value returned from `GetStatus()`. Check it out:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="progressBtn">Click Me</button>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="probar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var percent = 0;
    $('#progressBtn').on('click', function () {
        var intervalID = setInterval(updateStatus, 250);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/LongProcess',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            async: true,
            success: function () {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        });
    });
    function updateStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetStatus',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                percent = data * 10;
                $('#probar').css('width', percent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percent)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**PROBLEM:**

Unfortunately, the value returned by `GetStatus` is always zero. What am I doing wrong? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can not do this on the Server side. ASP.Net is designed to get the page send to the user so it can free the memory ASAP. Everything in the page Lifecycle is designed for this. If you need to do some multitasking, usually you have to add a extra WebService of some kind to do that job. Then query it from the Client side via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Christopher. Do you have any recommendations for a WebService that will enable me to create a simple progress bar for long server calls?

Comment: SignalR won't work for me due to incompatibility with IIS in Windows 7 in the [latest version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/tag/signalr/).

Comment: Progress bars are hard. First you need a code that is even able to report progress. And 99% of all code is not capable. So most of the times you have to take code you have and disect it down to a loop. Like itterate over files manually, rather then having one blocking call that does all the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `LongProcess` it is a new request. Then when you call `GetStatus`, there will be a request in each 250ms. Your controller class get initialized for each of these requests. Which means `Status` property would be zero for each of the `GetStatus`request.

Hope you get the idea. For more details please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132523/3668866).

What you can do is store the value of `Status` in a central place (example: in a database) and update that within the `SetStatus` method. Then within the `GetStatus` method, you can fetch the stored value.

Comment: I'm gonna try the database approach. Thank you for the tip Sampath!

Comment: Glad that helped you. :)